# Do repeated dictionary keys overwrite each other?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
 >>> dic={1:"a",1:"b",3:"c"}
 >>> dic[min(dic.keys())]

'b'
```

Though in dic both a,b have key values 1 why is the dic[min(dic.keys())] returns 'b'

Comment: for repeated keys a dictionary will return the last one

Comment: say `print(dic)` and see that you have the only key 1

Comment: Get enlightenment: `>>> dic`

Comment: What did you think your code should return? See how to create a [mcve] and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72706319/edit) the question.

Answer (score 3):

You can only store one of each key in a dictionary. Having two values both with a key of `1` will not work.

Therefore, after you have stored `1:"a"` in the dictionary, it gets replaced immediately by `1:"b"`, which you put in there next.

You can test this by printing the dictionary between the two lines. You will get:

```py
{1: "b", 3: "c"}
```

Therefore, when you index the dictionary with `1`, it will only return the last thing that you stored with that key - which is `"b"`.